# Capturing Date from String and doing Statistics

Tags: python, pandas

I have a XLS file with which has Time entries with various dates and times for those dates.

Example:

```
TIME_STAMP
21/04/2023 09:46:55.000
21/04/2023 09:46:55.858
21/04/2023 09:46:56.000
21/04/2023 09:46:57.000
21/04/2023 09:46:58.000
21/04/2023 09:46:59.000
21/04/2023 09:47:00.000
21/04/2023 09:47:01.000
22/04/2023 09:47:02.000
22/04/2023 09:47:03.000
22/04/2023 09:47:04.000
22/04/2023 09:47:05.000
22/04/2023 09:47:06.000
23/04/2023 09:47:06.000
23/04/2023 09:47:06.000
23/04/2023 09:47:06.000
23/04/2023 09:47:06.000
23/04/2023 09:47:06.000
23/04/2023 09:47:06.000
23/04/2023 09:47:06.000
```

I am trying to output total count of entries for the individual dates in this file with some basic stats like percentage of occurance compared to total occurances for each date.
So my output should show me count of entries for the three specific dates,i.e 21st 22nd and 23rd of April.
and for each date how many times they have occurred in the total data set.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

This is the code I tried :

```
df=pd.read_excel('TIME_Stamp.xlsx')


print('The total no of rows with DATE values is:')
print(df['TIME_STAMP'].count())
print('The stats for TIME_STAMP column is:')
print(df['TIME_STAMP'].value_counts())
```

Comment: you should try converting the datetimes with pandas.to_datetime https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html (if you haven't already). If you are only interested in the date and not the time, then you can access that by .date or any other value that you want. Then your code should be working fine

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use:

```
df['TIME_STAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME_STAMP'], dayfirst=True)

out1 = df['TIME_STAMP'].dt.date.value_counts()

out2 = df['TIME_STAMP'].dt.date.value_counts(normalize=True)
print (out1)
2023-04-21    8
2023-04-23    7
2023-04-22    5
Name: TIME_STAMP, dtype: int64

print (out2)
2023-04-21    0.40
2023-04-23    0.35
2023-04-22    0.25
Name: TIME_STAMP, dtype: float64
```

If need filter specific dates:

```
filt = ['2023-04-21','2023-04-22','2023-04-23']

df['TIME_STAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME_STAMP'], dayfirst=True)

dates = df['TIME_STAMP'].dt.date

out1 = dates[dates.isin(pd.to_datetime(filt).date)].value_counts()

out2 = dates[dates.isin(pd.to_datetime(filt).date)].value_counts(normalize=True)
```